# ol layer vector getSource addFeature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

can't get features added

`feat[0]` gets displayed but when it goes to the `for` iteration, I get ol.js error message :

> e.getId is not a function

here is my code:

```
var feat=donnees_points_postgis.getFeatures();
var couche_dalles_postgis=new ol.layer.Vector({
    source:new ol.source.Vector({
        features:(new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(feat[0].get('geom1'))
    })
});
map.addLayer(couche_dalles_postgis);
for(var i=1; i<feat.length; i++){
    if(feat[i].get('geom1')!=feat[i-1].get('geom1')){
        var feature=(new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(feat[i].get('geom1'))
        couche_dalles_postgis.getSource().addFeature(feature);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem may be that in the loop, you are using `readFeatures` but treating them as one feature using `addFeature`. Can you try using `addFeatures`?

Comment: whaou ! indeed I just replaced addFeature by addFeatures, and it does work !! Thanks a lot JeremyW !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution for adding features to a layer by getting data from a geometry column :

```
var feat=donnees_points_postgis.getFeatures();
var couche_dalles_postgis=new ol.layer.Vector({
    source:new ol.source.Vector({
        features:(new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(feat[0].get('geom1'))
    })
});
map.addLayer(couche_dalles_postgis);
for(var i=1; i<feat.length; i++){
    if(feat[i].get('geom1')!=feat[i-1].get('geom1')){
        var feature=(new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(feat[i].get('geom1'))
        couche_dalles_postgis.getSource().addFeatures(feature);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I see you're new to Stack Overflow. In the future, you should allow the person who answered your question to submit an answer for you to accept, so that they may get the credit.